# Chrome 62 and Flash

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, selenium, flash, cucumber

I have a Flash-based app that I need to test using Cucumber. As flash is not enabled by default I need to enable it before each test and whitelist the url I believe. If I pause the test in it's background phase I can manually set these options.

[image: flash option]

How can I automate this approach though, I have looked into adding `options` and `preferences`, but still cannot seem to get to work.

So this is my standard setup in an env.rb file

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  chrome_binary = '/Applications/Google Chrome.app'
  capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome("chromeOptions" => { "binary" => chrome_binary + '/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome' })
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome, :desired_capabilities => capabilities, :options => options)
end
```

Further reading has highlighted options such as

```
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
options.add_argument('arg-here')
prefs = {"enable flash here ? "}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
```

The `add_experimental_option` throws `undefined method add_experimental_option for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options:0x007fca30c10988>`

Has anyone automated this process?

Answer (score 2):

To enable `Flash` before each test and `WhiteList` the url you can use the following code block to configure the `WebDriver` instance to allow `Flash`:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.plugins", 1);
prefs.put("profile.content_settings.plugin_whitelist.adobe-flash-player", 1);
prefs.put("profile.content_settings.exceptions.plugins.*,*.per_resource.adobe-flash-player", 1);
prefs.put("PluginsAllowedForUrls", "https://your_url.com");
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Here you can find a detailed discussion on [**`Manage Flash in Chrome`**](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7084871?hl=en) and on [**`PluginsAllowedForUrls`**](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#PluginsAllowedForUrls)

### Update :

You haven't mentioned in your comment through which client you are not able to find `setExperimentalOption` or `set_experimental_option`. Here is the snapshot from my IDE which have no errors/warnings :

[image: flash]

And here is the [**JavaDoc**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeOptions.html) :

[image: setExperimentalOption]

Comment: Thanks for answering. Is there a Ruby version of this?

Comment: seems as if `setExperimentalOption` and `set_experimental_option` are undefined methods, did you have the same issue ?

Comment: Ive marked your answer as useful as it did help in some parts, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me in the end

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  chrome_binary = '/Applications/Google Chrome.app'
  prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.plugins" => 1,
           "profile.content_settings.plugin_whitelist.adobe-flash-player" => 1,
           "profile.content_settings.exceptions.plugins.*,*.per_resource.adobe-flash-player" => 1,
           "PluginsAllowedForUrls" => "hendricks-as3.localhost.bbc.co.uk"
          }

  capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome("chromeOptions" => { "binary" => chrome_binary + '/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome', "prefs" => prefs })
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome, :desired_capabilities => capabilities)
end
```

Reading this documentation helped me realise what to do. (also DebanjanB answer helped me with the specific profile options but as in Java no good to my specific needs, thanks though :-) )

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities