# How to enable Flash in Chromedriver 83 using python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to turn on flash on URL : http://tropicalatlantic.com/models/models.cgi?basin=al&year=2020&storm=03&display=wind_diagram&run=2020060612

```
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--disable-features=EnableEphemeralFlashPermission")

    chrome_prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.plugins": 1,
                "profile.content_settings.plugin_whitelist.adobe-flash-player": 1,
                "profile.content_settings.exceptions.plugins.*,*.per_resource.adobe-flash-player": 1,
                "PluginsAllowedForUrls": "http://tropicalatlantic.com/"}

    options.add_experimental_option("prefs",chrome_prefs)

    options.headless = False
    options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
    options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
    options.add_argument('log-level=3')
    options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    driver1 = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, service_log_path='NUL')
```

But this code doesn't work

Comment: Did you tried this link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51967309/activate-flash-in-chrome-selenium-with-python

Comment: @Dmitry yes i did, once page loads it blocks the plugin again

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I then switched Internet Explorer. I was using windows 10, which comes with internet explorer.

```
url = 'http://tropicalatlantic.com/models/models.cgibasin=al&year=2020&storm=03&display=wind_diagram&run=2020060612'
path_to_ie_driver = './iedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Ie(path_to_ie_driver)
driver.get(url)
```

On a few devices, IE by defaults open in zoomed condition raising an exception. You can maximize it before starting browsing.

```
driver.maximize_window()
```

Here is download link for IEx64 driver : [IE 64-bit Driver](https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.150/IEDriverServer_x64_3.150.1.zip)